# Wall Mounting a tv, how much can my wall take?

Tags: walls, mounting, new-home

I am looking to mount a 20lbs tv on my wall in a new condo. I am under the impression that the wall has been framed with 2x3 studs. I am unclear as to how much this could support. However, in an impulsive move, I bought a 15lb single stud mount for my television. I am wondering with the combined weight of 35lbscould damage my wall, given that it is an interior wall and the stud size is smaller than I had assumed.

My tv is 32inches (20lbs)
My mount is the Kanto M200 Wall Mount
My stud censor suggests that my studs are 13.5" apart (which I find odd, but that's what mapping my wall shows.)
And the wall is 115" long

Don't know if any of that helps.

Any answers would be much appreciated

Comment: 16" studs on center will have a 14" cavity between them. Find the other side of each stud, now you know the center of the studs. I hope you have wood framing and are pre-drilling for ~2inch long 1/4" lag screws. With metal studs I would use toggle bolts I guess. The wall can take the weight, the question is can your fasteners?

Answer (score 2):

A stud can hold much more weight than a 20 lb TV.

However, since your mount extends, that 20 lbs will actually add a lot more force to the mounting location.

You will still be fine as long as you are mounting directly to a wall stud. **You should be certain that you are screwing it to the center of the stud.**

Also, follow the installation instructions with the mount. With such a small mounting footprint, I think it is more important that you get everything correct.